# how to use javascript to open only ie window

Tags: javascript

I want a java script or j query script that opens internet explorer window.
with a new page.
that page from which we call this script running on any browser.

Comment: and if ie is not installed? (mac, linux...)

Answer (score 2):

No browser provides that capability.

In theory, it might be possible if you wrote (for instance) a Java Applet with sufficient security privileges to spawn Internet Explorer, but that would only work on systems with Internet Explorer installed and would require the user to grant the security privileges despite dire warning dialogs.

The best approach would be to eliminate whatever dependency the page has for Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

The Window's [open()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) method will open a new browser window.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function open_win()
{
    window.open("http://www.w3schools.com")
}
</script>
```

But if you want to force open an IE window only, then its not possible.